# an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added .net6 issue on adddbcontext

Tags: .net-6.0

I converted my .netcore3.1 project to .net6 because .netcore3.1 is deprecated now I can see below error after adding microsoft entityframework in .net 6

"An item with the same key has already been added. Key: server=""id="";password="";database="";convertzerodatetime=True;defaultcommandtimeout=120"

This error occured because addDbcontext added keys(connectionstring) multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be helpfull for people who want to convert .netcore3.1 to .net6
I used below code in Context File

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
  

      {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("");//add your connectionstring here
            }
    }
```

As well as i added this fix in startup.cs file this will allow only once to add adddbcontext

```
        bool isconfig = false;
        services.AddDbContext<GuardiansContext>(opts =>
        {
            if (!isconfig)
            {
                isconfig = true;
                opts.UseMySQL(sp.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationClient().GetConfigurationValue("").Result).EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            }
        });
```

Thanks,
Ashwinikumar